# Adding background in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flame

What should I do to apply my background image in my project? Did I miss something? My background image found under lib/assets/background.jpg

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  Util flameUtil = Util();
  await flameUtil.fullScreen();
  await flameUtil.setOrientation(DeviceOrientation.portraitUp);

  LangawGame game = LangawGame();
  runApp(game.widget);
}
```

langaw-game.dart

```
class LangawGame extends Game {
  Size screenSize;
  double tileSize;
  @override
  void render(Canvas canvas) {
    body:
    Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        image: DecorationImage(
          image: AssetImage("assets/background.jpg"),
          fit: BoxFit.cover,
        ),
      ),

    );
  }

  @override
  void update(double t) {}
  @override
  void resize(Size size) {
    super.resize(size);
    screenSize = size;
    tileSize = screenSize.width / 9;
  }
}
```

This is the result

[image]

This is the background

[image]

i dont have error receive but the image didnt refect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your image path is not correct. Now your image is under `lib/assets` folder, but you are trying to access `assets/background.jpg`. You need to edit with a full path like following:

```
AssetImage("lib/assets/background.jpg"),
```

Note: Also, check your `pubspec.yaml` file.

```
flutter:
  # The following line ensures that the Material Icons font is
  # included with your application, so that you can use the icons in
  # the material Icons class.
  uses-material-design: true

  # To add Flutter specific assets to your application, add an assets section,
  # like this:
  assets:
    - lib/assets/background.jpg
```

Read more from the [official document](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/assets-and-images).

Comment: `pubspec.yaml` why?

Comment: To be sure the given path is set correctly under the `assets:` section.

Comment: i dont have assets section in `pubspec.yaml` how?

Comment: I updated the answer. Please check the latest part.

Comment: i followed your instruction but the image still doesnt apply

Answer (score 0):

make sure in pubspec.yaml indention is correct.

flutter
1 tab for assets:
2 tabs for -assets/

Hope this helps